# Resultado de operador bitwise em Python

Tags: python, operadores, bitwise

Por que o valor de `~True` é `-2` e o de `~False` é `-1`?

O equivalente operador lógico `not`, em `not True`, resulta em `False` e vice-versa.

Answer (score 2):

Faça:

```
print(~1)
print(~0)
```

Dá o mesmo, certo? Afinal `True` vale `1` e `False` vale `0`. Portanto ele aplicou a operação de complemento nesses números quando está usando os literais booleanos.

O operador de complemento inverte os bits do número, todos os bits existentes mas compensando com o que se chama complemento, ou como se costuma aprender na escola, o "vai um". Ele não troca o sinal, ou inverte o número por algum critério, ele inverte o bits que compõe o número, até porque para todos efeitos números no computador são apenas sequência de bits.

Então quando tem um bit 0 ele vira 1, mas quando o bit é 1 ele vira 0 e vai um, portanto ele muda o bit de maior grandeza em seguida, então deve virar 10, que transformando em decimal dá 2.

A conversão ocorre inclusive com o bit do sinal se é positivo ou negativo, e o que era positivo vira negativo.

Então o 0 vira -1, e o 1 vira -2 (-10 em binário).

A fórmula em decimal mesmo para achar o valor correto é `-(valor + 1)`.

Tente isto para ver em binário:

```
print(bin(1))
print(bin(0))
print(bin(~1))
print(bin(~0))
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/JQ5J1q). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/flbuwtdr-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Math/Complement.py).

O operador de complemento não é o mesmo do operador relacional de negação, então os resultados são diferentes. Em um valor booleano o normal é usar o operador de negação que dá o resultado esperado e já conhecido pelo AP.

Python é uma linguagem de tipagem forte, *pero no mucho*, tem exceções, caso contrário essa operação nem seria possível.

Comment: Olá @Maniero! Na documentação do Python está escrito "The unary ~ (invert) operator yields the bitwise inversion of its integer argument. The bitwise inversion of x is defined as -(x+1). It only applies to integral numbers." O meu ponto é o seguinte: ~60 dá -61 por essa fórmula. Mas, se você fizer a "inversão" bit a bit, daria 1100 0011, pois 60 é 0011 1100. Então, qual é o sentido do valor -61 (que é o correto) se a "inversão" dos bits daria 195?

Comment: Lei de novo, não é só inversão, é inversão com complemento.

Comment: Ok. Mas, qual é o sentido dessa inversão com complemento? E como foi deduzida a expressão -(x+1)? Há algum texto que você me recomende que explique isso em detalhe num nível iniciante/intermediário?

Comment: A mesma que você aprendeu na matemática, quando você soma 7 com 5 não dá 2, dá 12, então precisa de complemento. A documentação dá a fórmula de forma precisa: `-(x+1)`